# Integrate my android application with existing POS(point of sale) system

Tags: java, android, point-of-sale

Is it possible to integrate a third party app with the already available Point of Sale Systems present in retails/restaurants?

Do they expose their APIs or any such thing where I will be able to integrate my system with them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's a question for the vendors of those systems.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils If u know something in specific to wincor-nixdorf. They provide tp-linux system. Is the only possible way is to collaborate with the POS company?

Answer (score 1):

No doubt, we can develop applications for them using Android. But, basically all the restaurants, retails don't use the same Software, that depends on them, which resource they are using. And we can't say whether they are exposing their API to develop the Android application or not. To make android application for those type of applications we need to talk with the application provider or we need to design our own API.

Comment: see by above comment. If you can tell something.

Comment: @Shubham Sorry I don't have any idea about that.